# Configure 2 gateways ppp0 + eth0

Tags: linux, networking

I have a server serving at 0.0.0.0 (for all interfaces) 
And my machine has 2 connections one ethernet eth0 and other a ppp0 (3G card)
First without the ppp0 connection active I have the following route table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         DD-WRT          0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I can access my server on local and outside networks

Next I have de ppp0 connection also active and have the following route table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
10.64.64.64     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Now my server can be accessed by both IP'S (192.168.1.149(local IP) and 89.214.60.196 (3g card)) but only in local network, in an outside network only ppp0 interface can be reached.

I need some help to configure 2 gateways one for this 192.168.1.149 and other for the ppp0 interface

Any help is welcome
Regards

Comment: What networks need to be reached on the eth0 network?

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to configure policy-based routing so packets that are response to traffic comming via ppp0 will leave the box via ppp0 [with the ip assigned to it], and similarly for eth0.

take a look at:

- http://linux-ip.net/html/adv-multi-internet.html
- http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html
- http://kudzia.eu/b/2006/01/poor-mans-multihoming-under-linux/ [some of my old nodes from setting similar configuration]

Answer (score -1):

192.168.x.x is not an Internet routable IP. See references at the bottom. You need to set up a NAT to allow translation between your LAN (192.168.1.0/24) segment and WAN 10.64.64.64 connection. In the case of your DD-WRT gateway, you do not need a NAT as that device will likely do it for you.

References

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network
- http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html

Comment: 10.64.64.64 also is a non-routable IP.